# rtl text shown out of order

Tags: css, reactjs, right-to-left, react-vis

I have a perisan text that is coming from the server. Under normal circumstances it would be shown like this:
ساعت12
and when i test it in different parts of my code it shows up fine. but when i use it in my charts the characters are shown out of order. Like this:
[out of order text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIrXw.png)

I have no idea why it is being flipped. i have tried to set `unicode-bidi` to both `embed` and `bidi-override`. I have tried different fonts. i have tried changing the font size. i have set the `direction` to `rtl` but so far none of these have worked.

Answer (score 0):

NVM. The letter spacing was too small and it caused the issue. setting it to inherit fixed the problem.